# how to shutdown web server

Tags: web, localhost

I am trying to create an offline web app from a practice book, and do not fully understand the quote below. First of all, how do you know you are using a localhost for a web server domain? Then, how do you shutdown the web server? Is the localhost domain referring to your device's router? If so, will turning off the router shutdown the web server? I would appreciate any help.

> If you are using localhost for the web server domain you will need to shutdown the web server to simulate offline mode, since even without network connectivity your browser can access the local host domain

Comment: turning off your router won't shutdown the local web server. i am assuming we are talking about IIS here which can act as a local web server. To shut it down for a particular application, you can stop the application pool which will take your application offline or you can stop the website altogether.

Comment: I am using OS X El Captain Version 10.11.4- the book I am learning from is Dane Cameron's 'A Software Engineer Learns HTML5 Javascript & jQuery'. You can find the offline web app code via the link 'Offline Web Applications' (under 'Resources'): http://cisdal.com/publishing.html

Comment: found out i am using mongoose web server v6.4

Comment: mongoose is an embedded web server, so I start to think that it **does run** on your router indeed. So the whole thread of discussion went in the wrong direction from the very beginning. Having this information read this web servers documentation or consider posting a new question, something around: 'how to configure and restart a mongoose web server v6.4`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of questions to be answered :-) 
Starting with the last ones:
**No**, the name 'localhost' does not refer to your router.
**No**, turning off the router will not shut down the web server

Update your question by giving the operating system, and the type and version of the web server you are considering. Then community may help by indicating what is the name of its configuration file (or other ways to check its configuration). Then you will be able to check in that file if the web server binds to localhost.
The same information will help with instructions to shut it down (BTW: does your practice book not mention how to shut down the web server????).
The most brutal way of restarting your web server is of course to restart the whole computer it is running on :-), but you anyway have to **start with checking** (and probably also modifying) **your web server's configuration**.
*localhost* is just the local name of your computer. Every computer can have some kind of 'public name' in addition to this. When configuring the web server, its administrator (its you now:-)) has to indicate what of these names should be used by the web server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response- how do you find out the type and version of the web server?

Comment: This is kind of a catch 22: depending on the operating system and on the type (and sometimes: version) of the web server, you do it differently... Disclose us anything more about your environment. Perhaps the title (ULR?) of the book will help us to identify it.